# Sails.js Associations many-to-many relation

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I have a problem with many to many relationship in sails and if somebody can help me it would be great :D

I have two models User and Message and the associations is defined as follows

api/models/User.js

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {         
    messages: {
      collection: 'message',
      via: 'owner',
      dominant: true
    }
  }
};
```

api/models/Message.js

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    owner: {
      model: 'user'.
      via: 'messages'
    }
  }
};
```

I checked in the DB (MySQL) the middle table is created and i successfully inserted the data but i cant retrive the data.

i start sails console and type

```
User
  .find()
  .populate('messages')
  .exec(function(err,r){
    while(r.length){
      var thisUser=r.pop();
      console.log(thisUser.toJSON())
    }
  });
```

But i always recive no data for messages, the messages field is always empty messages: []

my Current version of sails is 0.10.0-rc4

Comment: When you say you "successfully inserted the data", do you mean using Sails?  In that case can you show the code you used to insert the data?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?