# Displaying Model Association Data

Tags: sails.js

I'm trying to display many to many associations but everything I try returns undefined. I'm basically trying to do exactly what this guy here is asking [Sails.js Associations many-to-many relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912599/sails-js-associations-many-to-many-relation)
but he got no responses. I'm using postgres but I don't think that matters.

I can see the extra tables created to link the two entities. Basically I have a User, Group, Role Model. User has a many to many with groups and roles. When I look at the table the User model actually holds no information like group.name or role.name and the relationship table created only holds id numbers to reference the association. I'm assuming I need to find all roles in the association table that have user id match my current user id and display those.

Two questions, is there any other way to just display the associated records without querying by id. so user.roles.name (for example). Or how can I add the role/group name to the actual association table created by sails and not just display the id number.

User model

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    username: 'string',
    password: 'string',
    firstname: 'string',
    lastname: 'string',
    email: 'string',
    group: {
      collection: 'groups',
      via: 'users',
      dominant: true
    },
    roles: {
      collection: 'role',
      via: 'users',
      dominant: true
    }
  }
};
```

Group Model

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    name: 'string',
    users: {
      collection: 'user',
      via: 'group'
    }
  }

};
```

Role Model

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    name: 'string',
    users: {
      collection: 'user',
      via: 'roles'
    }

  }

};
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT

ejs file

```
<table>

    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Groups</th>
      <th>Roles</th>
    </tr>
    <% users.forEach(function(user){ %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= user.id %></td>
      <td><%= user.username %></td>
      <td><%= user.firstname %></td>
      <td><%= user.lastname %></td>
      <td><%= user.email %></td>
      <td><%= user.group.collection %></td>
      <td><%= user.roles.collection %></td>
      <td><a href="/user/edit/<%= user.id%>">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <% }); %>
    </table>
```

UserController:

```
users: function(req, res) {
    User.find().exec(function(err, users){
    res.view({users: users});
    });
  },
```

I've tried lots of different variations of user.roles and user.group. I'm guessing that's completely wrong though but didn't find much documentation on anything other then just setting up the many to many relationships.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to retrieve the records, and say what the output is that you're getting (versus what you expect)?

Comment: Sure I added it under EDIT in my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *populate* the associations when you  query for users, as demonstrated in the [documentation for many-to-many associations](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/ManytoMany.html).

```
User.find()
    .populate('group')
    .populate('roles')
    .exec(function(err, users){...}
```

OR

```
User.find().populateAll().exec(function(err, users){...}
```

Either of these will add a `group` array and a `roles` array to each individual user.  So if you leave your view code as is, you'll probably just get `[Object object]` for the output for those two columns.  You could use Lodash to at least create a comma-delimited list of names.  For example:

```
<td><%= _.pluck(user.group.collection, 'name').join(', ') %></td>
```

will give you a list of groups that the user belongs to.  Lodash is globalized by Sails by default, so you shouldn't have to add anything to your project to make this work.

Full docs for `.populate` are [here](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/waterline/queries/populate.html).

Comment: Ah thank you so much! I hadn't come across those docs before.